# Is $O(2^{n/2})$ the same as $O(2^n)$?

Tags: computational-complexity

Why or why not?  It seems like the answer should be no, but on the other hand, it's weird that you'd reach the same value in a constant multiple of n.

Comment: One may observe that, as $n \to \infty$, $\displaystyle \frac{2^n}{2^{n/2}} \to \infty.$

Comment: a constant multiple of $n$ has big consequences when $n$ is in the exponent

Answer (score 2):

$2^{n}$ is $O(2^{n})$ but it is not $O(2^{n/2})$.

Answer (score 1):

By exponent rules, $O(2^{n/2}) = O((2^{1/2})^n) \approx O(1.414^n)$ which clearly differs from $O(2^n)$ by more than a constant factor (consider the ratio).

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake once but if you write $x=2^n$, then you would have $O(x) = O(x^2)$ which of course doesn't make sense.

Comment: This answer doesn't work in general -- what if $x=2$? Then $O(x) = O(x^2) = O(e^x)$, which makes perfect sense (in this context, abusing notation in the way you do it by not viewing $x$ as a variable).